# How to get URL before loading a controller and using it as a return URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, web

I'm currently stuck in my "URL" retrieval problem.

So I have a function called changeactivation. I'm using codeigniter MVC, so this function is accessible via the URL. If a user clicks a certain link (perhaps, "activate" link), he or she will be redirected to the function, and the function will activate the account.

My problem is, after the function successfully do what it was supposed to do, I want to redirect the user exactly where he or she came from.

For example:

The source page is:

```
http://webiste.com/system/administrator/accounts/index/admin/user_id/desc/all
```

And to use the changeactivation function, the user will click:

```
http://website.com/system/administrator/accounts/changeactivation/123456789/
```

where 123456789 is the user ID.

After successfully doing the activation of the account, I want to redirect the user to `http://webiste.com/system/administrator/accounts/index/admin/user_id/desc/all` which is the source page.

`accounts` in the URL is the controller, its index needs a user type (ex. the "admin" in the url) to load the view where it'll load all the user accounts based on the user type specified. This is the reason why I can't just use `$this->index()`, without the user type it will just redirect the user to the home page. And besides, if there is pagination that rely in the URL, if I just use `$this->index()`, even with a proxy user type, it will just go back to the page 1, which is rather inconvenient.

What I wanted to happen is to get the URL before the user clicks the link, and use it as a redirection/return URL after the function works.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks to everyone who will answer.

Comment: put the url in a session and then retrieve it? but you need to be clear about many things. The request might be a POST request plus apply fiters. With CI, it is a pain though.

Comment: Sometimes, I tend to look for answers in the wrongest places. Using session never got to my mind. I'm so silly. That seemed to work best. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

$referer will bi the URL to the last page.